# Mid Side recording "Invert the Phase" - "Invert" is ghosted in Audition

Tags: field-recording, mixer, mid-side, phase

In Adobe Audition I'm following a YouTube tutorial trying to understand how to record and then manually process a “Mid Side” boom mic test recording.

So when I convert it to mono it gives me two channels.

One (the L) is the mid or center and the second channel (the Right) is the sides.

I’m told to duplicate the Right / Side track giving me 3 tracks and then “hard pan” one of the Right tracks to the Left and one to the Right.

Ok so far so good.  This is what I got (below) –I can clearly see the difference on the center vs the left right.

However it then tells me to “select the Right / Side add a mixer and invert the phase”

Any idea what “invert the phase” means and how I do that with a mixer?

[image: Screen Shot]

**Here's the files if if helps troubleshoot the problem.**
http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/H6

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/using/inverting-reversing-silencing-audio.html here, you want invert.

Comment: Um... Already saw that link before posting my question. If you look at the image I provided you can easily see that the option "Effects / Invert" is GHOSTED. Thus, the very reason I posted this question ;)

Comment: Hmm Odd. Maybe you need to choose the channel rather than the waveform?

Comment: Still remained ghosted. I added a link to the files in the original post -- in case anyone has a minute to kill.

Comment: Maybe a forum for the program, this stack is not the best for such a question :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same answer and stumbled onto the solution. You're currently in the "Multitrack" View. Inverting appears to only be available while in the "Waveform" view!